# Change Color Of Cell Based On Another

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I want cell R13 to turn color when it is less than or equal to S13.

Sorry if this is simple, I am having a hard time getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called **Conditional Formatting**. You can find it in the menu, under *Format -> Conditional Formatting*.
In the sidebar to the right, change the textbox under *"Format cells if..."* to *"Less than"* and put the following text there: `=S13`

Answer (score 0):

- right click the **R13** cell
- select Conditional Formatting

[image: 0]